# Android: Changing the height of root view of a layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm new to Android. Can anyone tell me how to change the height of `RootView` of a layout programmatically in Android? The code I've tried is given below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
            view.getRootView().getLayoutParams().height = value;
```

After executing this I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the above line.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The View returned by the inflate call is the root View, therefore this should work:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
view.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,<height>));
```

If you were to provide a ViewGroup to inflate into like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, containerForTheInflatedView);
```

Then `view` would be the ViewGroup, not the root View that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....While using this i'm able to get the root element of the main activity layout...but in my case i'm inflating a layout inside  an adapter and what i need is to get the root element of that layout...Can you help me?

Comment: When you inflate the layout inside the adapter you can just set new layout params (my 2nd piece of code) - or am I missing something? If so, please post your adapter code where you're inflating.